# Flex column with basis is not shrink

Tags: html, css, flexbox, tailwind-css

i have a flex column with child div as basis 300px and max-height limit 300px; i set it shrink and then add mini element the shrink is not work? why?

```
<div class="flex flex-col">
    <div class="basis-[300px] max-h-[300px] shrink bg-red">
        <div class="h-10 w-10 bg-blue"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Your CSS? Bootstrap or something else? (version?)

Comment: clear css; its tailwind.  but I think everything is clear there

Comment: No, there are just HTML and classes. Nothing can tell what it is. I've just added tailwind tag, next time don't forget to add related tag because it can help who is trying to answer your question know better what it is. :-)